# Multiple version of MS CRM on same server

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

My development server is having MS CRM 2013 Onpremises installed. It is possible to install MS CRM 2016 Onpremises on the same server?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. You can only share the backing SQL Server by creating Named Instances.

Comment: @Filburt,  you can write it as an answer :)

Comment: @GuidoPreite answered as requested by popular demand ;)

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible. You can only share the backing SQL Server by creating Named Instances.

You could use a CRM 2016 Online instance as an alternative, but it would introduce additional costs which is not desirable for a development environment.
The same applies for an installation to an Azure VM.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response :)